# ECDSA signing keys must be PrivateKey instances.] with root cause

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

when I try to register a new User I get the error ***

> *ECDSA signing keys must be PrivateKey instances.] with root cause*

***. I tried to change the signature algorithm but then a new error appeared saying that secret token was not secure enough. Based on the error, the problem appears to be in the **JwtService** Class shown down below:

```
`@Service
```

public class JwtService {

```
//constant secret key that must change
private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = "C:\\Users\\ihebt\\Documents\\security\\security\\src\\main\\resources/private.key";
public String extractUserEmail(String jwtToken) {
    return extractClaim(jwtToken, Claims::getSubject);
}

public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
}

public String generateToken(
        Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
        UserDetails userDetails
) {
    return Jwts
            .builder()
            .setClaims(extraClaims)
            .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
            .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.ES256)
            .compact();
}

public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver){
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply((claims));
}

public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String useremail = extractUserEmail(token);
    return (useremail.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
}

private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
}

private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
}

private Claims extractAllClaims(String jwt_token) {
    return Jwts
            .parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(jwt_token)
            .getBody();
}

private Key getSignInKey() {
    try {
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH));
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(privateKeyBytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read private key file", e);
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You have to generate private/public key for your JWT.

You can generate a JWT public and private keys using one of the following two utilities:

- openssl
- ssh-keygen

For example:

```
openssl genrsa -out ./private.key 4096
```

You should have in your current directory the private.key file containing your private key. Do not share this file with anyone and keep it secret. If someone obtained this private key, they would be able to impersonate you!

now you have private key, but in order to verify your jwt token you need public key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -outform PEM -out public.key
```

You can share this public key :)

After all this step you can use your private key instead of secret key. Enjoy coding :)